# Adding list to data grid when checkbox is checked

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am not fluent in WPF. I have a list in the data grid view and I also have a checkbox outside the Datagrid. I need to have an output that when the checkbox is checked it will add another row to the Datagrid. Here's the code that I have.

***.cs***

```
public InletPiping()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataColumn inletno = new DataColumn("Inlet pipe #", typeof(string));
            DataColumn pipeSize = new DataColumn("Pipe size (inch)", typeof(string));
            DataColumn actualID = new DataColumn("Actual ID (mm)", typeof(string));
            DataColumn roughness = new DataColumn("Roughness (mm)", typeof(string));

            dt.Columns.Add(inletno);
            dt.Columns.Add(pipeSize);
            dt.Columns.Add(actualID);
            dt.Columns.Add(roughness);

            dt.Rows.Add("Inlet Pipe 1", 10, 254.00, 0.0460);
            dt.Rows.Add("Inlet Pipe 2", 10, 254.00, 0.0460);
            dt.Rows.Add("Inlet Pipe 3", 10, 254.00, 0.0460);
            dt.Rows.Add("Inlet Pipe 4", 10, 254.00, 0.0460);
            dt.Rows.Add("Inlet Pipe 5", 10, 254.00, 0.0460);

            dataGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;

            DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
            DataColumn description = new DataColumn("Description", typeof(string));
            DataColumn unit = new DataColumn("Unit", typeof(string));
            DataColumn case1 = new DataColumn("Case 1", typeof(string));
            DataColumn case2 = new DataColumn("Case 2", typeof(string));
            DataColumn case3 = new DataColumn("Case 3", typeof(string));
            DataColumn case4 = new DataColumn("Case 4", typeof(string));
            DataColumn case5 = new DataColumn("Case 5", typeof(string));
            DataColumn case6 = new DataColumn("Case 6", typeof(string));
            DataColumn max = new DataColumn("Max", typeof(string));

            dt2.Columns.Add(description);
            dt2.Columns.Add(unit);
            dt2.Columns.Add(case1);
            dt2.Columns.Add(case2);
            dt2.Columns.Add(case3);
            dt2.Columns.Add(case4);
            dt2.Columns.Add(case5);
            dt2.Columns.Add(case6);
            dt2.Columns.Add(max);

            dt2.Rows.Add("Mist fraction - predicted", "%", "0.00", "0.00");
            dt2.Rows.Add(" ", " ", " ", " "," "," ");
            dt2.Rows.Add("Mist flow rate", "m/hr", "0.00", "0.00");

            dataGrid2.ItemsSource = dt2.DefaultView;
        }
```

***My Xaml***

```
        <StackPanel Margin="10,0,10,0">
            <Grid Margin="0,10,0,20">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="6*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Text="Results"  Grid.Column="0"/>
                <ComboBox  Margin="10,0" Height="30" SelectedIndex="0" MinWidth="140" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Grid.Column="1">
                    <ComboBoxItem Content = "Inlet pipe 1"/>
                    <ComboBoxItem Content = "Inlet pipe 2"/>
                    <ComboBoxItem Content = "Inlet pipe 3"/>
                    <ComboBoxItem Content = "Inlet pipe 4"/>
                    <ComboBoxItem Content = "Inlet pipe 5"/>
                </ComboBox>
            </Grid>
            
            <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid2" ColumnWidth="*"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel>
            <Grid Margin="10,10,0,0">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="6*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                
                <CheckBox x:Name="a1"   Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Override predicted misfraction"  Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            </Grid>
            
        </StackPanel>
```

This is my output. When the checkbox is checked data will appear on the space that I put red on it

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could insert a new row to the `DataTable` in a `Checked` event handler like this:

```
private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataView dv = dataGrid2.ItemsSource as DataView;
    DataRow newRow = dv.Table.NewRow();
    newRow[0] = "";
    newRow[1] = "";
    newRow[2] = "";
    newRow[3] = "";
    newRow[4] = "";
    newRow[5] = "";
    dv.Table.Rows.InsertAt(newRow, 1);
}
```

Comment: this works sir but it creates another column in  the the table. it doesn't insert to the space row like in the picture that I have attached..

Comment: @angel1108: Why would it create another column? It creates another row. You can set the column values for that row to whatever you want.

Comment: I mean row sorry. what I mean is row. It will add another row not inserted to the space that I encircled.

Comment: @angel1108: In my example, it inserts the row at index `1`. You can change the second argument to whatever index you want to insert it into.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a Checked event in the Checkbox of your XAML as shown below.

```
<CheckBox x:Name="a1"   Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Checked="A1_Checked"/>
```

In the xaml.cs add the code to handle this event

```
private void A1_Checked(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var row =(dataGrid.ItemsSource as DataView).ToTable().AsEnumerable().Where(x => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Convert.ToString(x["Description"]))).FirstOrDefault();
            if (row != null)
            {
                row["Description"] = "Add whatever you want";
                row["Unit"] = "Add whatever you want";
                ....

                 dataGrid2.ItemsSource = dt2.DefaultView;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hello sir. it doesn't work sir. It says ```dt2 does not  exist in the current context```.

Comment: it says ```System.ArgumentException: 'Column 'description' does not belong to table .'```